# How to change only a specific letter at a specific index in a string to uppercase/lowercase

Tags: python, string

Here is the code:

```
def upper_every_nth (s, n):
    i = 0
    while len (s) > (i * (0 + n)) :
        character = s[i * (0 + n)]
        s = s.replace(character, character.upper(), 1)
        i = i + 1
    return (s)
```

I want it to return a string that is identical to s except that every nth character (starting at position 0) is uppercase.

```
>>> upper_every_nth("cat", 2)
'CaT'
>>> upper_every_nth("hat", 3)
'Hat'
```

The problem is I cannot use the.replace method since it replaces all the occurrences of that letter in a string if not, only the first occurrence.

So let's say the string is 'deer'. I want to convert the second occurrence of 'e' to upper case. But with .replace method, it is either I get 'dEEr' or 'dEer'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to work with indices. Here is how you can replace the `k`-th character of string `s` with character `ch`:

```
s = s[:k] + ch + s[k+1:]
```

To understand how `s[:k]` and `s[k+1:]` work, have a read of [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation). The `+` simply concatenates several strings together.

Comment: Ill try it right away, will get back to you in a sec, thanks by the way for the response...

Comment: It worked but please can u explain to me how the statement above works, I'm still new to the world of programming and I hate making something work without knowing how it worked...

Answer (score 0):

```
def upper_every_nth(word, n):
    return ''.join(value if index%n else value.upper() for index, value in enumerate(word))
```

Testing

```
>>> upper_every_nth('dictionary', 3)
'DicTioNarY'
```

To break this up more explicitly, you can use a `for` loop

```
def upper_every_nth(word, n):
    newWord = ''
    for index, value in enumerate(word):
        if index % n == 0:
            newWord += value.upper()
        else:
            newWord += value
    return newWord
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2.x or 3.x, use a list of single-character strings.  In 3.x, you can also use a bytearray:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python3

'''Demonstrate capitalizing every nth letter of a word'''


def upper_every_nth_via_list(word, number):
    '''Capitalize every nth letter of a word'''
    new_word = []
    for index, value in enumerate(word):
        if index % number == 0:
            new_word.append(value.upper())
        else:
            new_word.append(value)
    return ''.join(new_word)


def upper(character):
    '''convert character to uppercase if lowercase'''
    if ord(b'a') <= character <= ord(b'z'):
        character += ord(b'A') - ord(b'a')
    return character


def upper_every_nth_via_bytearray(word, number):
    '''Capitalize every nth letter of a word using a 3.x byte string'''
    new_word = word[:]
    for index, value in enumerate(new_word):
        if index % number == 0:
            new_word[index] = upper(value)
    return new_word


def main():
    '''Main function'''
    string = upper_every_nth_via_list('abcdefgabcdefggfedcba', 3)
    print('{}\n'.format(string))

    input_bytearray = bytearray(b'abcdefgabcdefggfedcba')
    bytearray_string = upper_every_nth_via_bytearray(input_bytearray, 3)
    print('{}\n'.format(bytearray_string))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
word = ''
while len(s) > i:
    if i % n == 0:
        word = word + s[i].upper()
        i +=1
    else: 
        word = word + s[i]
        i +=1
return (word)
```